# Why won't toast work as expected with client side form action?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a client component. In this component I have a form with several inputs. When the user clicks "Save Changes" this triggers the form action to run. The form action is client side code that contains a server action which runs on the server. I know that it's client side because it immediately logs to the client console. Everything works as expected except that the loadingToast does not render on the screen until immediately after updateProfileAction() is done and then immediately is dismissed and then the other toast pops up. I'm using react-hot-toast and shadcn/ui for some of the html elements. Here is the function:

```
const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

const handleEditProfile = async (formData: FormData) => {
const loadingToast = toast.loading("Updating profile...");
console.log(
  "This is logged to the client immediately but the loadingToast does not show up until after updateProfileAction() is finished.",
);
new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

startTransition(async () => {
  const { success } = await updateProfileAction(formData);

  toast.dismiss(loadingToast);
  if (success) {
    toast.success("Profile successfully updated!");
  } else {
    toast.error("Failed to update profile!");
  }
});
};
```

Here is the html:

```
<form action={handleEditProfile}>
  <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
      <Label htmlFor="name" className="text-right text-black">
        Name
      </Label>
      <Input
        id="name"
        name="name"
        defaultValue={user.user_metadata.name}
        className="col-span-3 text-black"
        disabled={isPending}
      />
    </div>
    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
      <Label htmlFor="avatarUrl" className="text-right text-black">
        Profile Picture
      </Label>
      <Input
        id="avatarUrl"
        name="avatarUrl"
        className="col-span-3 text-black"
        type="file"
        disabled={isPending}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input
    type="hidden"
    name="oldAvatarUrl"
    value={user.user_metadata.avatar_url}
  />
  <DialogFooter>
    <Button type="submit" disabled={isPending}>
      {isPending ? "Saving changes..." : "Save changes"}
    </Button>
  </DialogFooter>
</form>
```

When I instead run a function that is called from a button click rather than a form submission it works as expected. Ultimately all I want to be able to do is get the data from the inputs and pass them into this handleEditProfile function so I could use useState and then pass them into an onClick function but I don't want to have to do that. I also just want to understand why this is behaving like this.